# Inconsistency between audit & display: Prior reputation kept or lost for community wiki posts?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, community-wiki

#### Summary:

*Upvotes received before marking community wiki don't show in the rep audit, and upon triggering a recalc, are subtracted from the score in the page header, but remain in the profile screen reputation log.*

---

In the canonical [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), it is stated that reputation earned or lost before wiki mode is retained.

> The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.

After answering an "easy" question, I marked it community wiki expecting a lot of not that well deserved upvotes were likely to roll in.  At the time I marked the community wiki option, I think I had already 3 upvotes on the answer and it quickly went up to 5.  Assuming all the reputation would go away, I checked meta and found the statement above.

Looking at my reputation audit (via https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) however, all the prior upvotes on that answer disappeared though my rep counter in the header hasn't yet recalculated to reflect that. Based on the documentation we have, ~3 upvotes would have remained in the reputation audit.

I have no particular need for the points from those upvotes and expected they would go away, but that's inconsistent with our "official" documentation on the matter.  So, has the behavior changed?  Does the community wiki reference answer just need to be updated?

### Edit 1:

If those points don't remain in the audit and a recalculation occurs, do they stay or go?  Past experience tells me that recalculation (manually from the button on the audit or automatic) sets the displayed score to that listed in the audit.  *So which one is correct in this case?*

### Current inconsistency between audit & display:

**Current display showing 290 for the day with +40 for question 11692959:**

> [image: Header rep]

**Current audit which shows +250 for the day and nothing for question 11692959:**

> [image: Rep audit]

### Edit 2, clicked Recalc Button:

**After clicking the Trigger Recalc button, the display goes back to the value from before any upvotes, score now consistent with the audit (+250 for today)**

> [image: recalc header display]

**But the reputation log still shows +40 for the answer and +290 for today**

> [image: recalc list display]

Comment: If CW was not in effect at the time of the upvotes, you should have gotten the rep. It's not just documentation - that's how the system works (or at least, how it _used_ to).

Comment: @Oded That's what I thought would happen, but while my header rep count shows the points earned, my audit does not, and I suspect the header will be updated to reflect it overnight. Maybe this needs a [bug] tag too.

Comment: It looks like you had already hit the rep cap for the day, so that might be why you don't see these upvotes included.

Comment: @Servy I hit the rep cap during that group of upvotes. 4 of them should show with +10, and the other one earned prior to community wiki should show in the audit with +0.  The audit chunk above only shows +160 from upvotes today.

Comment: Wild idea: Have you checked the "Show removed posts" checkbox on the reputation page? Maybe there was a post deleted where you had a +4 answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer I had "Show removed posts" checked already. Result is the same either way, showing 290 for today in the log and 250 in the header.

Comment: That wouldn't have removed the upvotes from the audit anyway, hadn't thought it through.

Comment: Weirdness abounds with this! For a couple of minutes after the new GMT day turned over, the mysterious 40 points reappeared in my header score, then disappeared again. It coincided with being re-awarded +10 for an upvote that happened after I had falsely passed my rep cap for Jul 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692959/url-post-not-hitting-isset-post/11692978#11692978), then yes, you got reputation from 4 upvotes on that post, as seen in your reputation history:

[image: 40 earned from CW answer]

As far as the reputation audit, I'm not sure. I haven't actually used that audit page in some time. There are a lot of things in the reputation history that don't show up on the audit, though.

Comment: That is the answer in question, and my understanding with the rep audit had been that when a recalc occurs, it is the audit whose score becomes the final word.  I guess that needs clarification too.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the recalc button to see what happens? I just checked my audit and posts which I've gotten upvotes for which were later made community wiki are still included.

Comment: That makes it a bit weirder.  The header display reverts to the audit score w/o votes for that answer, but the rep log (like your image above) still shows the votes and score the inflated score.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the fact that you made the post community wiki within the 5 minute grace period. Maybe the reputation auditing system doesn't like that, or doesn't see that the post was ever a regular post before being community wiki.

Comment: I think the supposition in this previous comment is correct. Twenty points from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21070133/revisions) just disappeared into the ether. I got the two upvotes _before_ I converted it to CW, but it was within the grace period. Probably counts as a bug, but there may not be any good way to fix it because of the way CW status is stored.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Interestingly, I also saw the same thing last week -  I had an answer that got +2 in the first few seconds before I made it CW. About 5 minutes later as I was looking at the header, 20 points disappeared. It does seem something to do with the grace period.